# Compare All php Framework to check which is More Efficient

Tags: php, mysql

We are on the way to build Social Networking Website.

For this, i was comparing all the available framework in php. I come out with YII and Zend.

Now i am stuck that which is better Framework which utilities less Resources and gives best output.Consider that I am doing code optimization and database optimization already.

Any help will be Appropriated ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Facebook had a real challenge to expend with PHP, now they are using a custom compiler/interpreter that convert the PHP code. Here is a link... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP

Comment: If you're worried about performance, why are you using PHP?

Comment: Since it is open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined method to scale PHP is: add hardware. It doesn't attempt to scale in any other way.

This is successful because hardware is cheap, and adding it is easy. It does mean that before you start writing a project in PHP you must have the budget to cover the hardware your project will consume once deployed.

Facebook have an un-ending source of income, with massive investment from companies like Microsoft, collectively reaching the region of billions of dollars; this enabled them to invest hugely in an infrastructure that could support their application - and it STILL failed.

Facebook went about it all wrong, there's a well known saying "*more money than brains*"; they are deploying PHP on servers with 8 or 16 cores, and PHP can only utilize one at a time, and can only do one thing at a time. It's basic maths, their application would scale better if it used ALL it has at it's disposal.

http://docs.php.net/Thread

The real, correct answer, from somebody *with* brains.

You might think, yeah but hiphop compiles real code, surely it supports threading; but it doesn't, they never even tried:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/blob/master/doc/threading

I am the author of pthreads, I'm not suggesting that it is ready for you to develop your application, but I am suggesting that pthreads presents a viable means of scaling applications beyond "add hardware", you should eat everything on your plate before asking for seconds, it's called "manners".
I do need for people to jump on board and start developing their ideas using pthreads, but it cannot be considered stable yet. If you think in PHP then it shouldn't take long to prototype your ideas, find out for yourself if pthreads is suitable and if it isn't, file a bug report or get in touch by any other means.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like other large webapps is largely scaled by hardware and Frameworks don't effect it as much as software engineering practices anyway! If you're working on a new product, you should be concentrating on the product itself and not get consumed by its performance at this stage.

When the day comes, having performance issues will be the best problem you could have. i.e. you will have a large user base)

Good luck!